# Golang ZMQ Push/Pull - Fail Push if no Pullers

Tags: go, zeromq

I'm using ZMQ in Golang to exchange messages with a GNURadio application.

I have it set up as the Go application PUSHing messages to a PULL block in GNURadio.

I'd like to configure it in Go such that a PUSH returns an error if there are no PULLers on the same socket. i.e. I don't want to allow pushing into the void; I want to know that a PULL received the message.

Some other questions/examples I've seen seem to suggest that this is how the PUSH/PULL works by default (blocks until something can receive), but in this Go example it just keeps pushing even if nothing is pulling, and throws no errors.

```golang
port := 1234
pusher, err := goczmq.NewPush(fmt.Sprintf("tcp://127.0.0.1:%d", port))
if err != nil {
    return err
}
b := []byte("hello world")

for {
    // I'd like this to return an error if there are no PULLers on the socket
    if err := pusher.SendFrame(b, 0); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

Unfortunately I'm restricted to PUSH, PULL, PUB, SUB, REQ, and REP, because GNURadio doesn't support the more advanced patterns like DEALER/ROUTER.

REQ/REP isn't an option because it's a one-way system, there will never be a response.

Comment: Hello, I see two problems. One is that the sample code constructs a REPLY (`goczmq.NewRep`) instead of a PUSH (`goczmq.NewPush`). The other, more important, is at the level of semantics. You cannot know from a PUSH side if the receiver received it (PUSH, as all other zeromq sockets, has a queue (length is tunable, but the default is 1000 or infinite depending on the zeromq version) and is thus non-blocking until the queue fills up) or if, once received, processed it (PUSH/PULL is one-way).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the Rep/Push issue. I had accidentally copied some code that I was comparing with. Are you familiar with how to adjust the queue length in Go?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use socket monitor. You can get data out of this that tells you when a peer has connected, or when you have connected to a peer (depends on which is binding and connecting). Use this to determine when the connection to GNURadio has come up, and send data to it only once that has occurred.

It's not quite what you asked for, but the combination of "have connected" and ZMQ guaranteeing delivery means that success should occur. It's the opposite of being told there is an error - being told there's no barrier to success.